# Postman request showing IBM cloud down for maintenance

Tags: ibm-cloud, postman, devops-services

I am trying to send post request to create a toolchain on ibm cloud but getting this error mentioned in screenshot since last three days.

Why this error is coming up,am i doing something wrong?

Also i checked ibm none of the servers are down,cloud is normal
[image]

EDIT:So now i am able to create the toolchain,seems it was Authorization token error.
But now i am not Able to add a delivery pipeline through an api to an existing toolchain,is this functionality provided in IBM?

Comment: Did the POST work before? I have used GET requests over the past weeks and it works.

Comment: No my POST request never worked...also My GET request is just returning generic CREATE TOOLCHAIN PAGE ,seems autocreate is not working..sample Get Request  { https://cloud.ibm.com/devops/setup/deploy?repository=https://github.com/open-toolchain/simple-toolchain&orgGuid=sample&spaceGuid=sample&apiKey=sample&env_id=ibm:yp:eu-gb&autocreate=true}

Comment: Do you have provisioned that service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are trying to understand your situation, but we have not been able to reproduce that Error 500 and "IBM Cloud console is down for maintenance" error you're seeing.

Could you try it again and let us know the datestamp&timezone of when you tried (so we can check our logs)?

Also can you give us the details of your default region, please?, as in if you open

https://cloud.ibm.com/devops/toolchains

does it redirect to:

https://cloud.ibm.com/devops/toolchains?env_id=ibm%3Ayp%3Aeu-de

or to some other non-(eu-de) region?

We did see this entry in the log files:
`[2019-07-31T15:06:43.934] [ERROR] template-v2 - Failed to read template from repo https://github.com/open-toolchain/simple-toolchain, branch master, type null: Authorization header contains invalid or expired credentials.`

but that occurs when using an invalid Authorization header token, and the response to the browser is not Error 500, but is Error 400 with:
`"errorDetails\":\"Property 'access_token' either missing or empty \"`

Also, when attempting to create the open-toolchain/simple-toolchain template, it doesn't work; it gives Error 400:
`"description":"Failed Schema Validation at prod-region,prod-organization,prod-space,api-key for pipeline"`

but creating a toolchain works ok using the repository:
https://github.com/open-toolchain/headless-toolchain

Comment: Yes it does redirect to "https://cloud.ibm.com/devops/toolchains?env_id=ibm%3Ayp%3Aeu-de"...also timestamp for my requests(2019-08-02T15:10 IST to 2019-08-02T3:14pm IST)..Also i am not able to get both GET and POST request to work.

Comment: Also when trying GET Request on browser it just loads the page with filled fields as per parameters but does not create it automatically.*I did add autocreate=true*

Comment: So now i am able to create the toolchain,seems it was Authorization token error. But now i am not Able to add a delivery pipeline through an api to an existing toolchain,is this functionality provided in IBM?

Answer (score 0):

You can provision a toolchain with components such as a delivery pipeline using a GET request. The building blocks are described in the [documentation for the IBM Cloud Continous Delivery service as part of creating a "Deploy" button](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/ContinuousDelivery?topic=ContinuousDelivery-deploy-button).

There are some tutorials that use that deploy button to build more complex solutions, like the [secure-file-storage](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/secure-file-storage), [logistics-wizard-toolchain](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/logistics-wizard-toolchain), or [insurance-toolchain](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/insurance-toolchain).

The GET request starts off a more complex flow because you need to log in, often provide values, etc. So I would recommend to try that request in a browser and not POSTMAN.

Comment: How do you provision a Get Request for Delivery pipeline?This link you mentioned tells about deploy button to be included in my applications.

Comment: Also when trying GET Request on browser it just loads the page with filled fields as per parameters but does not create it automatically.*I did add autocreate=true*

Comment: And, can you then go ahead and kick off the creation?

Comment: i am now able to create toolchain also I have provided edits to my question,Can you please help again? :)

Comment: The question changed. Please mark this closed or delete it and open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I am now able to create toolchain using POST request.

I was using wrong token for Authorization and got confused since no error message was shown instead "IBM cloud is under maintenance" popped up.